# Import-Export:Import images as planes not working Blender 2.8

Tags: add-on

The extra option is not listed in Mesh-
[image]

I have checked the Add-on..
Then too this occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is under Images below the objects, putting it there with reference images as well
[image]

If you still can't find the option, make sure that the add-on is enabled. Open the preferences window and enable the images as planes add-on.

[image]

Comment: It worked..,grateful.